# Cos'è "l'inconsulto"?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel racconto *Il cielo di pietra*, di Italo Calvino, ho letto questa frase (il corsivo è mio):

> Ma per Rdix, attratta come sempre dal raro e dall'*inconsulto*, c'era l'impazienza d'appropriarsi di qualcosa d'unico, buono o cattivo che fosse.

Ho letto la [definizione dell'aggettivo "inconsulto" nel vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/inconsulto/). Comunque, non sono sicura di aver capito cosa sia "l'inconsulto" nella frase precedente. Significa che Rdix era attratta dal rischio in modo imprudente?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***[Inconsulto](http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/I/inconsulto.php)*** è un aggettivo, usato some sostantivo nel testo di Calvino, che si riferisce ad atti,  gesti o altre azioni fatte in maniera avventata, con imprudenza.

> - Fatto senza riflettere, in modo avventato, temerario, imprudente: *atto, gesto inconsulto; un'impresa inconsulta.*

Il significato sembra riferirsi al fatto che Rdix sia attratta dalle cose rare e dalle azioni fatte in maniera inconsulta.

Answer (score 0):

I have just voted for John61's answer, but the following may be of some interest. (Ho appena votato per la risposta di Josh61, ma quanto segue può essere di qualche interesse)

From Dizionario Inglese - Italiano - Ragazzini/Biagi, 1991: "Inconsulto: ill-advised; unadvised, rash" and "malaccorto, sconsiderato, imprudente, avventato, inconsiderato, impetuoso, precipitoso".

Word Reference adds: "sudden, thoughtless".

I would add, though not for that particular case (Aggiungerei, anche se non per il caso specifico): "malconsigliato, sconsigliato".